# Joomla 3.2: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 479

Tags: joomla, joomla3.2

My website Joomla 3.2 website was running well recently, when I got this error message and things don't work anymore.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 479

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 483

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 483

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 479

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 483

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\Apache2\htdocs\ictogcio\libraries\cms\application\site.php on line 483
Error displaying the error page: Could not find template "".
```

Comment: have you installed any extensions recently or have any server setting been changed?

Comment: Yes I enable the Multilanguage module.

Comment: Did you try disabling it? And what about server settings, have any of those changed? If you're using a company host, it would be a good idea to ask them

Comment: You can't just enable the module ... did you enable the plugin as well? And did you set up the home pages etc? Multilingual involves a lot of steps.

Comment: Everything went well and the website was ready and completed. However, after enabling the Langauage Switcher, the website brings up the above error when I bring it up on the localhost on my machine